# How do I make Unison behave like rsync?

Tags: linux, rsync, unison

I have two roots, `/sync` and `ssh://bob@remotehost//sync`. These roots contain three subfolders: `paul`, `bob` and `sam`. I currently sync them using the following script:

```
rsync -a --delete --delete-excluded --delete-after --force\
  /sync/paul/ bob@remotehost:/sync/paul
rsync -a --delete --delete-excluded --delete-after --force\
  bob@remotehost:/sync/bob/ /sync/bob
unison /sync/sam ssh://bob@remotehost//sync/sam
```

I want to create a unison profile that manages all three sub folders. So far I have the following:

```
# Define roots and paths
root = /sync
root = ssh://bob@remotehost//sync
path = paul
path = bob
path = sam

# Preserve timestamps
times = true

# Force single direction for some paths
forcepartial = Path paul/* -> /sync
forcepartial = Path bob/* -> ssh://bob@host//sync
```

Using this profile I expected all changes in `/sync/paul` to be propagated to `ssh://bob@remotehost//sync/paul` and all changes in `/sync/paul` to be forcibly deleted. I also expected vice versa for the path `bob`. However, this is not what I am seeing. In my test runs Unison wants to propagate new files and folders in both directions for both paths `paul` and `bob`.

How can I make Unison behave like `rsync -a --delete --delete-excluded --delete-after --force $SOURCE/ $DEST` for the paths `bob` and `paul`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out `forcepartial = Path paul/* -> ...` does not match sub file- and foldernames beginning with a dot (e.g. `paul/.config`). However, one can use `BelowPath paul` or `Regex paul/.*` instead. The following use of `BelowPath` would achive my goal:

```
...
forcepartial = BelowPath paul -> /sync
forcepartial = BelowPath bob -> ssh://bob@host//sync
```

The same but using Regex instead:

```
...
forcepartial = Regex paul/.* -> /sync
forcepartial = Regex bob/.* -> ssh://bob@host//sync
```

[This](http://www.pcurtis.com/diary16.htm) page suggests that the Regex keyword can be used to match subfolders as well, implying that `forcepartial = Regex somefolder/.* -> ...` would match the folder `paul/somefolder` and all its children. I have not experimented with this so I cannot say.

Comment: I can recommend not using Unison for syncing home folders for desktop users, at least not on a slow HD. The constant flux of state files for apps like Chromium, Firefox, etc makes the Unison index phase last an eternity on each sync session.